# How does one disable USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR for only one variable in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

My `settings.py` has `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True` because that's generally what I want in my templates.

However, what can I do to prevent this default behaviour for only one of my variables in a template?

`{{ project_id }}` currently prints "9,324", but I want it to display "9324" instead.

Cheers!

Comment: convert it to string before adding to context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Filter **`stringformat`** formats the variable according to the argument, a string formatting
> specifier. This specifier uses the printf-style String Formatting
> syntax, with the exception that the **leading “%” is dropped**

```
{{ project_id|stringformat:"s" }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Django has excellent [localization support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#topic-l10n-%20templates). E.g. in your template you can temporarily disable localization with

```
{% load l10n %}

[...]

{{ project_id|unlocalize }}
```

which will temporarily disable adding thousand's separators to numbers.